# How to add multiple modules from 1 package

Tags: typescript, module, aurelia

I'd like to import 2 modules from the package [string-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-template). `string-template` consists of the 2 files `index.js` & `compile.js` which both export a module.

I tried to accomplish this using the following approach:

**1) Add both modules to the `vendor-bundle` dependencies in `aurelia.json`:**

```
{
    // ...
    "bundles": [
        {
            // app-bundle
        },{
            // vendor-bundle
            // ...
            "dependencies": {
                // ...
                "string-template", // Points per default to index.js which works just fine
                {
                    // Use some custom name and point it explicitly to the second module. Doesn't work...
                    "name": "string-template-compile",
                    "path": "../node_modules/string-template",
                    "main": "compile"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**2) Include them where needed (e.g. in `foo/bar/code.ts`):**

```
import * as Format from 'string-template';
import * as FormatCompile from 'string-template-compile';
```

**Problems**

If I only include `string-template` within `aurelia.json` & my source code, everything is working as expected but as soon as I add the second module with the custom name `string-template-compile` the following happens:

- Typescript tells me `TS2307:Cannot find module 'string-template-compile'.` where I try to import the module (`foo/bar/code.ts`)
- The CLI process started with `au run --watch` stops execution after the output `Tracing foo/bar/code...` without any additional error.

I've run into the same issue when trying to only import specific modules from [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) to only use `crypto-js/aes` & `crypto-js/sha256` instead of including the whole package (described as "modular include" in the NPM usage section).

---

**Edit:** I've also created [an issue](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/502) in the [CLI repo](https://github.com/aurelia/cli) since it doesn't seem like I'm actually getting an answer here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use *require*, this works (tested with esnext project not ts):

```
//aurelia.json
{
    "name": "string-template",
    "path": "../node_modules/string-template",
    "main": "index"
}

// js
const format = require('string-template');
const compile = require('string-template/compile');
```

Update: as for require-js each module have one or more dependencies:

- sha256 module needs only: core
- aes module needs: core, enc-base64, md5, evpkdf, cipher-core
- enc-base64 needs: core.
- md5 needs: core.
- evpkdf needs: sha1, hmac.
- cipher-core needs: core, evpkdf.

so for the two modules sha256 and aes you need to load 8 files:

```
// aurelia.json
{
    "name": "crypto-js",
    "path": "../node_modules/crypto-js",
    "main": "core",
    "resources": [
        "enc-base64.js",
        "md5.js",
        "hmac.js",
        "sha1.js",
        "evpkdf.js",
        "cipher-core.js",
        "sha256.js"
    ]
}

// js
import core from 'crypto-js';
import 'crypto-js/sha256';
import 'crypto-js/aes';

// usage
let ciphertext = core.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123');
let bytes  = core.AES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), 'secret key 123');
let plaintext = bytes.toString(core.enc.Utf8);

console.log(plaintext);
```

Comment: This is working for the `string-template` example where I actually want to use all modules from the package but using this approach includes the complete `CryptoJS` lib in `vendor-bundle.js` even though I'm actually using only 1 or 2 modules.